# How to create two different websites using WordPress locally

Tags: wordpress, vs-web-site-project

I want to know how to create two different websites using WordPress on a local computer. Now I've got one site and I need to develop another one. It's a completely different one. Tell me how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain what difficulty you faced

Comment: I need to create another web site.. I ave installed bitnami.. I need dashboard for a new web site

Comment: You can use the multisite concept in WordPress. https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a local server with a tool like MAMP (mac) or WAMP (windows), then put each wordpress deployment inside a separate folder in the web root of the local server:

```
webroot/wpsite1
webroot/wpsite2
```

Then depending on how your local server is setup, you would hit each site by going to something like:

```
http://localhost:8000/wpsite1
http://localhost:8000/wpsite2
```